# Why is using foreign key to fetch data sending me an error?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I'm just trying to fetch data using a foreign key and while it does it's job correctly I'm getting a strange error and i really don't know why since i found similar code on internet and it works just fine.

```
try {

        Laptop lpa;
        session.beginTransaction();

        Student myStudent = session.get(Student.class, 2);
        lpa = myStudent.getLaptop(); //error refers to this line of code

        System.out.println(lpa.getVrsta());

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();

    } finally {
        sf.close();

    }
```

And it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: 
    Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:mysql://....
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oto_otm_mtm.Blogic.main
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966566/why-is-it-sending-me-an-unclosed-connection-error-when-everything-should-be-clea

Comment: You are closing the session but you are not closing the established database connection. Hence the connection leak. Please close the database connection. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: @Jabongg Hibernate's session usually manages the JDBC connection behind the scenes.

Comment: Not sure about that link, I'm just following a youtube tutorial, anyway that solution doesn't work on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing two problems here; one is [the `NullPointerException` that's making your program crash in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), and then the leak detector is triggering because you call `session.close()` in the `try` block (and so if there's an exception, it gets skipped).

Your `lpa` is probably `null` because there's no record with primary key 2.

(Also note that the style you're using is obsolete; at a minimum, use JPA interfaces (`EntityManager`) with try-with-resources, and preferably use managed transactions like Spring `@Transactional`.)

Comment: You solved the null pointer exception but i still keep on getting ERROR: Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:mysql://... Is it because my approach is obsolete maybe?

Comment: @aratata Did you move `session.close()` into the `finally` block (or use try-with-resources)?